# Python Compare dataframe contents and replace if match?

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison, equals

I am working on a small program as practice in python and need some help trying to compare two columns in a data frame and replace the contents of one with another. I can see my results as I have converted the data frame to excel.

Anyway, I want to compare two columns `Location` and `Abbrev` based on the first three letters of each and then replace with the abbreviation. So the `LON` in `Abbrev` column should be compared with first three letters in *London*. The `Abbrev` column only gives one abbreviation instance.

So I start with:

```
Team         Location    GameDay   Abbrev
Arsenal      London      2/14      LON
Liverpool    Liverpool   2/14      LIV
Manchester   Manchester  2/16      MAN
Arsenal      London      2/23      NEW
Newcastle    Manchester  2/16      LEE
```

and I want to get this output:

```
Team        Location  GameDay   Abbrev
Arsenal     LON       2/14      LON
Liverpool   LIV       2/14      LIV
Manchester  MAN       2/16      MAN
Arsenal     LON       2/23      NEW
Newcastle   MAN       2/16      LEE
```

However, right now I am only getting a full replacement of the columns regardless of match.

```
Team        Location    GameDay   Abbrev
Arsenal     LON         2/14      LON
Liverpool   LIV         2/14      LIV
Manchester  MAN         2/16      MAN
Arsenal     NEW         2/23      NEW
Newcastle   LEE         2/16      LEE
```

This is the piece of code I have.

```
df['Location'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Abbrev'] 
                          if row['Location'][:3].upper() != row['Abbrev'] 
                          else row['Abbrev'],axis=1)
```

I would like help figuring out whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `row['Location'][:3]` is in abbreviations:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Arsenal', 'London', '2/14', 'LON'],
        ['Liverpool', 'Liverpool', '2/14', 'LIV'],
        ['Manchester', 'Manchester', '2/16', 'MAN'],
        ['Arsenal', 'London', '2/23', 'NEW'],
        ['Newcastle', 'Manchester', '2/16', 'LEE']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Team', 'Location', 'GameDay', 'Abbrev'])

abbreviations = set(df.Abbrev.values)
df['Location'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Location'][:3].upper() if row['Location'][:3].upper() in abbreviations else row['Abbrev'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         Team Location GameDay Abbrev
0     Arsenal      LON    2/14    LON
1   Liverpool      LIV    2/14    LIV
2  Manchester      MAN    2/16    MAN
3     Arsenal      LON    2/23    NEW
4   Newcastle      MAN    2/16    LEE
```

**UPDATE**

If you prefer a one-liner:

```
df['Location'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Location'][:3].upper() if row['Location'][:3].upper() in df.Abbrev.values else row['Abbrev'], axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't understand, abbreviations is not hard-coded it depends on the dataframe. Anyway I updated the answer with a one-liner.

Comment: Its because I'm practicing on working with more than five values. I have 30 entries, and am trying not to manually input all 30, if that's a better explanation of what I'm trying to practice.

Comment: I see this answer is meant as an example, you can change `df` by anything you want.

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting a direct swap. Rather than it finding a match and replacing it. Is there a better way to iterate through both of the dataframe columns?

Comment: Weird, I ran the code and it worked, what did you tried?

Comment: df['Location'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Location'][:3].upper() if row['Location'][:3].upper() in df.Abbrev.values else row['Abbrev'], axis=1)

Comment: Can you post the data where it fails? As an additional example in your question?

Comment: It's the same result as in the original post. It's swapping replacing the full column, rather than checking for a match.

Comment: Well I works for me for the data in the original post. So Is hard to know where it fails ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I 100% understand, but based on just the example data you could do:

```
df['Location'] = df['Location'].str[:3].str.upper()
```

But it sounds like you want the location to only be filled with values from `Abbrev`, you don't say what you want the behavior to be if the value isn't in `Abbrev`, so I'll assume `NaN`:

```
# Map to first 3 letters
df['Location'] = df['Location'].str[:3].str.upper()
# null out values not in Abbrev
df.loc[~df['Location'].isin(df['Abbrev']), 'Location'] = np.nan
```